# Different exception handling in XP and Vista

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

I have a weird issue. Say you have the following:

```
Application.ThreadException += something;

try
{
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Now given an exception happens somewhere in the app, Vista raises the `ThreadException` event, but XP just jumps straight to the catch block.

How do I get the handling to behave the same? In `something` I need to handle some cleanup, but it never goes there with XP. Consequently, the `FormClosing` event never fires from the catch block as all forms are disposed at that stage.

Notes:

- Both systems run .NET 3.5 SP1, same version
- Only difference is the OS

Thanks

Comment: "Somewhere in the app" means it happens in the main thread or in some other thread?

Comment: The exception happens in the main/UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscrive to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event instead. That's always thrown if an application doesn't handle its exception.

Btw, a try-catch around an Application.Run() statement is considered bad practise as far as I know.

Comment: I would like not to handle it that way either, but it seems it is the only way to catch (but not handle) them currently in XP (as a last resort).

Comment: That's because you handle the exception within your catch block. Either use an UnhandledException handler OR try-catch around the Application.Run; applying both won't work, at least not under XP :)

Comment: Hmmmm, that sounds fishy, let me try that  :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [`UnhandledExceptionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.unhandledexceptionmode.aspx) has a different default value on Vista? Have you tried playing around with this setting? You can explicitly force a mode by calling

```
// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go 
// through our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Comment: Ahh, saw that ages ago, will see what it does from work tomorrow (+1 in the mean time ;p )